# How to get Facebook Friend List in ASP.NET?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building an App with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Identity.
So far the login is working correctly.
Here the auth:

```
var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
fb.Scope.Add("email");
fb.Scope.Add("friends_about_me");
fb.Scope.Add("friends_photos");
fb.AppId = "";
fb.AppSecret = "";
fb.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider() {
    OnAuthenticated = async FbContext => {
        FbContext.Identity.AddClaim(
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", FbContext.AccessToken));
    }
};
fb.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);
```

I'm trying to get the friends list. I've been looking for a few examples but none is working with this version of MVC 5.
My question is. How can I fetch all the friends with this version?

I don't want to use Javascript API, I want all the code in c# and then send to the view.

I think I just need to rewrite the login and store the access token in the session, and then simply call `var client = new FacebookClient(TOKEN);`
So how can I rewrite the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got everything you need. The `OnAuthenticated` callback you've set adds a claim containing the access token for Facebook. You just need to pull the claim for the user:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var facebookClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FacebookAccessToken");
if (facebookClaim != null)
{
    // access facebook API with `facebookClaim.Value`
}
```

And if it exists, then you can use the Facebook API to pull in their friends by making standard HTTP calls via something like `HttpClient`.

Comment: perfect. it works adding `var client = new FacebookClient(facebookClaim.Value); dynamic me = client.Get("me");`
but how can I list all friends. `me/friends` doesn't work

Comment: @bramalho: With API v2 you don’t get all friends of the user any more, only those that are users of the app as well. (And yes, this _has_ been discussed countless times before already, and is also clearly described in FB docs and changelog …)

Comment: thank you for the explanation. so there's some way to list some friends. ie: i would like to list some friends to invite to use the app (my app doesn't use canvas, is a web page)